# All TCP packets have the PSH flag set - who / what would be responsible for that?

Tags: tcp

On a server->client TCP stream, all packets from the server have the PSH flag set. Is good old Nagle responsible for this flag being set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The push flag (`PSH` or `P`) is set by the sending host. If the sending application uses write or send of 100 bytes, each packet will have `PSH` set. If the sender sends 2000 bytes, it will be sent in two packets, and the second will have the `PSH` flag, assuming standard frame size of 1500.

The push flag indicates to the receiving host that the received data should be passed to the receiving application immediately.

Comment: I see. But how about when Nagle joins multiple small messages and more than 1500 bytes accrue, would the first packet's PSH be set or not?

Comment: You might have better a better crowd to answer your question at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks, I [did](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53072/49973) just that.

Comment: Your source for this assertion?

Answer (score 0):

> The setting of the Push Flag is usually not controlled by the sending
>   application, but by the sending TCP layer. Most modern TCP/IP stacks
>   set the PSH bit at the end of the buffer supplied to send() .

Source:  [Improve latency for TCP by not waiting for Push flag](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcp-push-flag.html)

Comment: The PSH flag is set on the entire outgoing segment, not 'at the end of the buffer'. Answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user207421 The data supplied to `send()` can be larger than the maximum segment size (MSS), in which case it is sent in multiple segments. I suppose what is meant here is that the segment containing the last fraction of the data will have the `PSH` flag set.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the P bit all the time is a standard correct, but inefficient behavior that you might see coming from old TCP stacks.